# Update all items in a RecyclerView asyncronsously on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view I want to update one attribute of each item after the initial creation to provide the user with a nicer experience. I would like to do this asynchronously as it takes time to get the data.

How do you iterate over the items in a recycler view and subsequently update. I moved from listview to recycler because it has a the method NotifyItemChanged.

So Ideally I would like to do

```
void OnRefresh(IList<data> data)
{
    Data = data;
    NotifyDataSetChanged();

    Task.Run(() => UpdateAllAttribute1Fields());
}

void UpdateAllAttribute1Fields()
{
    foreach(var myItem in myRecyclerView.Items)
    {
        UpdateAttribute1(myItem));
    }
}
```

But I do not understand how to access myItems. On windows (sorry), in a listview this would be listview.items I think.

I could save the views OnBindViewHolder but that will be a bit more work.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to iterate over all items in recyclerview to update, Just set the RecyclerView to point to your custom data set. And asynchronously update the data set whenever you want. You can then notify the recyclerview that the data in the dataset has changed with the following methods of its adapter (which will automatically update the recyclerview content)

`adapterObj.notifyItemChanged(pos)` //for one object

`adapterObj.notifyDataSetChanged()` //for the entire dataset

`adapterObj.notifyItemRangeChanged(start, end)` //for a range

Comment: Yep that did the trick however the updates only occur when I scroll. I do not want scroll.

Comment: Actually the rule of thumb in Android is, if any view is out of window bounds, we shouldnt draw it (Efficiency purpose).
Idea of RecyclerView is kind of same, It draws the views below only when they come to focus (visually available).

So if the view is below (not visible in scroll), those viewholders are recycled for new views that come to focus. Thats how recyclerview works. So theres no point in trying to update the views which are not in screen

Comment: Be assured that, if you follow this method, whenever views come to focus, it will have the updated information. Since the dataset was updated and adapter was notified.

Comment: Excellent idea not updating until you screen for the ones out of sight. Not great for the ones in view though. I have tried scrolling programatically and this works if I do each row but obviously looks horrible. Scrolling only once to row 0 either before or after the first update only updates row 1 strangely. If I subsequent manually scroll the data is correct.